# jquery binding button to show up on textarea

Tags: jquery, binding

First off here is the link to my script where I am having problems:
[Link to the script](http://www.gewrew.com/?url=jhadu82:1)

My Script;

Click anywhere on the image to create a comment, that part works.
When you click on an existing comment and add a comment it works, but when you try to add another comment it does not work.  Can someone please help me with the bindings?

**EDIT:**
When you enter a comment then go to another tab/comment no add comment box shows.

My Source Code for my js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        getComments();

        var imgClass = "proof",
            bodyEle = $('img.' + imgClass).parent(),
            id = 0,
            currentDot,
            currentDiv,
            tabAdded = false,
            currentTabID,
            viewingTab = false,
            status = false;

        /*$("img." + imgClass).mouseover(function( ){
            $(this).css("cursor", "url(lib/images/cursor-2.png)");
            console.log('hmmm');
        });
        $("div.proof_container").on('click', function(){
            if(status){
                $("#nDiv_" + (id - 1)).remove();
                $("#nDot_" + (id - 1)).remove();
            }
        });*/
        $("img." + imgClass).on("click", function(event){

            if(viewingTab){
                $('.nBox').each(function(){
                    $(this).hide();
                });
                viewingTab = false;
            }

            var offset = $(this).offset(),
                leftE = (event.clientX - offset.left),
                topE = (event.clientY - offset.top);

            //error testing
            /*
            console.log('Offset: ' + offset);
            console.log('Left: ' + leftE);
            console.log('Top: ' + topE);
            */

            var newCon = $('<div class="com_container"></div>'),
                newDot = $('<img src="lib/img/circle.png" width="25px" height="25px" class="nDot" />'),
                newDiv = $('<div class="nBox"></div>'),
                newForm = $('<form name="nForm" id="nForm" method="post"></form>'),
                newText = $('<textarea name="nText" class="nText"></textarea>'),
                newLeft = $('<input type="hidden" class="nLeft" name="nLeft" />'),
                newTop = $('<input type="hidden" class="nTop" name="nTop" />'),
                newButton = $('<input type="button" name="nButton" value="Add Comment" />');

            if(status == false){

                //css
                newDot.css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'left': (leftE + 3),
                    'top': (topE - 13)
                });
                newDiv.css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'left': (leftE + 24),
                    'top': (topE + 8)
                });

                //id's
                newDot.attr('id', 'nDot_' + id);
                newDiv.attr('id', 'nDiv_' + id);

                //set currents
                currentDiv = $("#nDiv_" + id);
                currentDot = $("#nDot_" + id);
                id++;


                newDiv.append(newForm);
                newForm.append(newText);
                newForm.append(newLeft);
                newForm.append(newTop);
                newForm.append(newButton);
                newButton.hide();


                newLeft.val(leftE);
                newTop.val(topE);

                bodyEle.append(newDot);
                bodyEle.append(newDiv);

                status = true;


                //textarea change
                newText.bind('input propertychange', function() {
                    if($(this).val() == ""){
                        newButton.hide();
                    }
                    else{
                        newButton.show();   
                    }
                });

                //button submit
                $(newButton).on('click', function( ){
                    //check to see if tab has already been added
                    if(tabAdded == false){
                        //create tab
                        $.get("createTab.php", {left: leftE, top: topE}).done(function(data){
                            var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                            tabAdded = true;
                            currentTabID = obj.tab;
                            //create comment
                            $.post("test_add.php", {comment: newText.val(), tab_id: currentTabID}).done(function(data){

                                //getName
                                $.get("get_name.php").done(function(data){

                                    var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                                    var newComment = $('<div class="comm">' + newText.val() + '<br />-' + obj.name + '</div>');
                                    newForm.before(newComment);
                                    newButton.hide();
                                    newText.val("");

                                });

                                getComments();
                                return;

                            });
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        $.post("test_add.php", {comment: newText.val(), tab_id: currentTabID}).done(function(data){

                            //getName
                            $.get("get_name.php").done(function(data){

                                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                                var newComment = $('<div class="comm">' + newText.val() + '<br />-' + obj.name + '</div>');
                                newForm.before(newComment);
                                newButton.hide();
                                newText.val("");

                            });

                            getComments();
                            return;

                        });
                    }

                });
            }
            else{

                if(tabAdded){
                    $("#nDiv_" + (id - 1)).remove();
                    tabAdded = false;
                    currentTabID = "";
                }
                else{

                    $("#nDiv_" + (id - 1)).remove();
                    $("#nDot_" + (id - 1)).remove();
                }

                status = false;
            }


        });


        function getComments(){

            var project_id = '1'; //testing purpose

            $.get( "get_comments.php", { project_id: project_id }).done(function( data ) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                //testing info
                console.log(obj);

                for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){

                    var newTabLeft = obj[i].tab.left,
                        newTabTop = obj[i].tab.top,
                        newTabID = obj[i].tab.comment_id;
                        newTabDot = $('<img id="tab_' + newTabID + '" src="lib/img/circle.png" width="25px" height="25px" class="TDot" />'),
                        newTabDiv = $('<div id="tabDiv_' + newTabID + '" class="nBox"></div>'),
                        newTabForm = $('<form name="nForm" id="nForm_' + newTabID + '" method="post"></form>'),
                        newTabText = $('<textarea name="nText" id="nText_' + newTabID + '" class="nText"></textarea>'),
                        newTabLeftInput = $('<input type="hidden" id="nLeftInput_' + newTabID + '" class="nLeft" name="nLeft" />'),
                        newTabTopInput = $('<input type="hidden" id="nTopInput_' + newTabID + '" class="nTop" name="nTop" />'),
                        newTabIDInput = $('<input type="hidden" id="nIDInput_' + newTabID + '" class="nTop" name="nTabID" />'),
                        newTabButton = $('<input type="button" id="nButton_' + newTabID + '"name="nButton" value="Add Comment" />');

                    //css
                    newTabDot.css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'left': (parseInt(newTabLeft) + 3),
                        'top': (parseInt(newTabTop) - 13)
                    });
                    newTabDiv.css({
                        'position': 'absolute',
                        'left': (parseInt(newTabLeft) + 24),
                        'top': (parseInt(newTabTop) + 8)
                    });

                    newTabDiv.append(newTabForm);
                    newTabForm.append(newTabText);
                    newTabForm.append(newTabLeftInput);
                    newTabForm.append(newTabTopInput);
                    newTabForm.append(newTabIDInput);
                    newTabForm.append(newTabButton);
                    newTabDiv.hide();
                    newTabButton.hide();

                    bodyEle.append(newTabDot);
                    bodyEle.append(newTabDiv);

                    //addcomments before form
                    for(var x = 0; x < obj[i].comments.length; x++){

                        var newCommentBox = $('<div class="comm">' + obj[i].comments[x].comment + '<br /> - ' + obj[i].comments[x].client_name + '</div>');
                        newTabForm.before(newCommentBox);


                    }

                    //textarea change
                    $('#nText_' + newTabID).on('input propertychange', function() {
                        console.log('being changed');
                        if($(this).val() == ""){
                            $('#nButton_' + newTabID).hide();
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#nButton_' + newTabID).show();   
                        }
                    });


                    $("img.TDot").on('click', function(){

                        if(status){
                            console.log('This Is Being Called');
                            $(".nDot").each(function(){
                                $(this).remove();
                            });
                        }

                        $('.nBox').each(function(){
                            $(this).hide();
                        });


                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        var newId = id.split("_");

                        $('#tabDiv_' + newId[1]).show();
                        viewingTab = true;
                    }).on('mouseover', function(){
                        $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    });

                    newTabButton.on('click', function(){

                        $.post("test_add.php", {comment: newTabText.val(), tab_id: newTabID}).done(function(data){

                            //getName
                            $.get("get_name.php").done(function(data){

                                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

                                var newComment = $('<div class="comm">' + newTabText.val() + '<br /> - ' + obj.name + '</div>');
                                newTabForm.before(newComment);
                                newTabButton.hide();
                                newTabText.val("");

                                $('nText_' + newTabID).bind('input propertychange', function() {

                                    if($(this).val() == ""){
                                        $('nButton_' + newTabID).hide();
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $('nButton_' + newTabID).show();    
                                    }
                                });

                            });

                            getComments();
                            return;

                        });

                    });
                }
            });

        }
    });// JavaScript Document
```